# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, typeerror, openpyxl

I'm working on project that handle excel documents with python.
I'm trying to select the cell in partition.

```
excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook('file_directory')
sheet = excel_document.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1') //I changed directory and 
sheet name to simple names.
day_num = 1
start_cell_ = 'A' + str(3 + (day_num-1) * 12)
end_cell_ = 'J' + str(day_num*12)
print(start_cell_, end_cell_)
test_data_ = sheet[start_cell_, end_cell_]
```

The error code is

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-0d5ce3e639b6> in <module>()
      5 end_cell_ = 'J' + str(day_num*12)
      6 print(start_cell_, end_cell_)
----> 7 test_data_ = sheet[start_cell_, end_cell_]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    343             key = str(key
    344                       )
--> 345         min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)
    346 
    347         if not any([min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row]):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py in range_boundaries(range_string)
    131     Cell coordinates will be converted into a range with the cell at both end
    132     """
--> 133     m = ABSOLUTE_RE.match(range_string)
    134     if not m:
    135         raise ValueError("{0} is not a valid coordinate or range")

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Help this python newbie :)

Comment: formatting change

Comment: You are accessing the range incorrectly. You have to use slicing: `sheet[start_cell_: end_cell_]`. Not the colon instead of the comma you use.

Answer (score 0):

From `openpyxl` documentation:

**Accessing many cells:**

Ranges of cells can be accessed using slicing

> > > cell_range = ws['A1':'C2']

So from your code change the line `test_data_ = sheet[start_cell_, end_cell_]` to

```
test_data_ = sheet[start_cell_:end_cell_]
```

Link: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells